# Bluetooth can't find any device

Tags: bluetooth

After maintenance, my Macbook Pro Retina can't find any bluetooth device (Magic Mouse / Keyboard / Soundbar / Phone)

I read many instructions, reseted SMC and NVRAM, but nothing changes

[image: apple.com.Bluetooth.plist]

[image: system report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: service master didn't connected all three wires, that come to antenn.
[image]